# Eagle: LD1117 from Sparkfun library has wrong pinout?

Tags: eaglecad

I did insert in schematic the LD1117 V3.3, from Sparkun library. I need to convert 5V to 3v3.

Device selected is V_REG_LD1117VXX, package 78XXL.

I want use it for LM1117v33 (or LD1117V33). This is the datasheet:

https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/LD1117V33.pdf

When I did switch to board, seems to me that PINOUT is inverted (from Left to Right I red IN/GND , GND/3.3V and OUT/5V) and also the names on it are wrong.

I attach an imagine (small and larger). Where am I wrong? Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: I just looked up the datasheet for AMS1117 and it has no PTH version. Please provide a datasheet for the device you are referring to. (also, 78XXL is not a package name, its a family of another ubiquitous regulator. So if the library has mixed names for devices, its likely that the actual package is not for the AMS1117)

Comment: Always verify third party libraries, SparkFun makes a lot of parts that are never device-proven. It isn't unrealistic to find a part that is incorrectly made. Luckily it looks like a standard package, it would be very easy to make your own part.

Comment: @WesleyLee You are right. I did wrong the name of selected components. Edited question. Thank you

Comment: I looked into the datasheet, seems that the connections are different than the package. The order in the package is the same as in the 78XX family, so I think this is a different device that happens to be in the wrong "place".

Comment: Old library, wrong connections? I tried V_REG_LD1117VXX from 'SparkFun-IC-Power.lbr' on [github](https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun-Eagle-Libraries) and pinout was correct, but package is slightly different to yours - which suggests your library is an old or modified version. Note that text 'I - O' on the _package_ does not match the actual pin functions.

Comment: @BruceAbbott How can I solve? Other than I could insert a 3-conn and use it, instead of entire package? Thank you!

Comment: Install the latest library from my link, or edit the device in your library to check/change it to the correct pinout. You could also edit the package and remove the 'I - O' text (which doesn't affect routing, but might mislead someone who is using the board). To help us properly answer your question, can you show us the relevant part of your Eagle schematic with nets labeled?